# Python: How to get the total number of hits of a elasticsearch query

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I'm having fun doing some experiments using `Elasticsearch` with the `Enron` email dataset. I did a query to get something that's not important for my actual question. I obtained a total hits of 4 and I'd like to print this number as:

`The total number of hits is: 4`

My question is: How can I get the total number of hits?

This is my query:

```
s = Search(using=client, index="enron_test").query('range', date={'gte': query_date_1, 'lte': query_date_2, "format": "dd/MM/yyyy||dd/MM/yyyy"})
```

and this is the result of the query taken from `Sense`:

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
       ...
```

Comment: `s["hits"]["total"]`

Comment: If I write down `print(["hits"]["total"])`, it fails returning `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`.  If I write down `print(s["hits"]["total"])` with `s`, it returns `<elasticsearch_dsl.search.Search object at 0x7f87f6698d50>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'url','port':'9200','timeout':60}])
result=es.search(index='your index',doc_type='your doc_type',body={'query':your query})
print(result['hits']['total'])
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'url','port':'9200','timeout':60}])
res = es.count(index='your index', doc_type='your doc_type', body={'query': your query })["count"]
```

If it helps you, here are good examples of count with Python:

https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/elasticsearch/Elasticsearch/count/python-elasticsearch-count-method-examples.html